# jquery mobile and jquery ui not compatitble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

am working on a html5 application that will work on both desktop,tablets and mobile devices.am stuck when it comes to using progress bars and dialog boxes.at first i had been using jquery mobile but its only until now when i want to incorporate jquery ui inorder to use progress bars and dialog pop ups is when i came to realize that the two are not working out well when used together. this is a sample code of the effect of the two plugins

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>dialogbox demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />   
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>        
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().lowStorageSpace();
    });

        $.fn.lowStorageSpace = function () {
            $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
          .html('<div><h5>You are running out of space.backup or sync data before you proceed!!</h5></div>')
          .dialog({
              modal: true, title: 'Low storage space!!', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
              width: 'auto', resizable: true,
              buttons: {
                  Sync: function () {
                      //sync();
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  Backup: function () {
                      // backup();
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  Cancel: function () {
                      //cancel();
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              },
              close: function (event, ui) {
                  $(this).remove();
              }
          });

        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code works well when i comment out jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js. but i really need it too in my complete app.
any help on how i can use the two will be appreciated.
i have seen many similar questions but non has solved my problem
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict i agree. Out of all the examples of jquery ui and jquery mobile i have seen i have not seen code showing that the two can be used on the same script. I would use two different scripts, one for ui and one for mobile. That way there should not be any conflict here.

Comment: @John...in my case using different scripts wont work as am working on one html page with several pages in it.